# Implementing map<int, mpz_t> in C++ (GMP Library)

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, stl, gmp

I'm currently having some trouble using the GNU Multiple Precision Library in the C++ STL Container map.

Here is the code I am having trouble with:

```
void getA(int termNum,map<int, mpz_t>& A_Recurrence, mpz_t A)
{
    if(!A_Recurrence.count(termNum-1))
        getA(termNum -1 , A_Recurrence, A);

    else
    {
        mpz_t temp;
        mpz_init(temp);
        mpz_set(temp, (A_Recurrence[termNum]));

        mpz_mul_si(temp, temp, 2); //temp *= 2;
        mpz_add(A, temp, A_Recurrence[termNum-2]); // A = 2*A_R[t-1] + A_R[t-2]
        mpz_set(A_Recurrence[termNum], A); //A_Recurrence[termNum] = A... 
//Save the value for later use in calculating this for larger termNums
    }
}
```

In my program, I have a `map<int, mpz_t>` that, given an integer, has an mpz_t as a value. When I attempt to access the mpz_t element at a given integer index, I get the following error:

`/Applications/Xcode.app/.../c++/v1/memory:1673:20: Object expression of non-scalar type '__mpz_struct [1]' cannot be used in a pseudo-destructor expression`

Looking more into the specifics, the line causing me trouble is 
`93:36: In instantiation of member function 'std::__1::map<int, __mpz_struct [1], std::__1::less<int>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<const int, __mpz_struct [1]> > >::operator[]' requested here`

and in this case, line 93 is `mpz_set(temp, A_Recurrence[termNum])`

It appears I cannot directly access an mpz_t from a map... Are there any ways around this? My algorithm depends on accessing previous mpz_t's from the map.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please use the C++ wrappers (include `<gmpxx.h>` and use `mpz_class`).

Comment: From [this](https://gmplib.org/manual/Parameter-Conventions.html) page, "...the GMP types mpz_t etc are implemented as one-element arrays of certain structures." If you need `mpz_t` you can take the actual type, and either store it in the map or store pointers to it.

Comment: @James Root  When you say "take the actual type and store it in the map", what do you mean by this? Don't I already do that? Also, if I were to store pointers of mpz_t's, how would I go about doing that? Would I need to do something like the following? `mpz_t *temp = new mpz_t; `? Because when I do that, I get the following error: "Cannot initialize a variable of type `mpz_t` with an rvalue of type `_mpz_struct *"

Comment: @RicardoIglesias By actual type, I mean the type that `mpz_t` is an array of. You can use [`remove_all_extents`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_all_extents) to get it.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with remove_all_extents or how to use it, so I think I'll try using mpz_class as an alternative... With that said, how would you use the mpz_class? I found out that the type of the entries in the `map<int, mpz_class>` were of type `10__gmp_exprIA1_12__mpz_structS1_E` and was wondering how to use them as mpz_t numbers

Comment: Okay. I managed to work with the mpz_class using the map. The way I worked around the limits of std::longs is as follows. When converting from mpz_class to mpz_t, I converted the class to a string, and got the string to an mpz_t using the mpz_set_str method, which led to expected behavior.

Comment: mpz_class is used like an int, you can write x=y+z, z*=2, whatever. As for "converting from mpz_class to mpz_t" through a string, that doesn't make sense, mpz_class is a wrapper that contains an mpz_t, and you can access that mpz_t with z.get_mpz_t().